# Why it shows in console "[object File]" but not object itself?

Tags: javascript, windows

```
fs.addEventListener('change', function () {

    for (name of this.files)
        console.log(name)
    }

});`
```

What's wrong with my computer? Windows 7;

Comment: `const name`. This fails in strict mode — for a good reason. Use [modules](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), not scripts in sloppy mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below snipet to for file name

```js
fs.addEventListener('change', getFileData);

function getFileData() {
  const files = this.files;  
  for ( let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   console.log("file " + (i+1) +" name", files[i].name);    
  }
}
```